# Solving the G - equation with method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Trying to solve

$$u_t = |\nabla u|  \quad u(0,x) = e^{-|x|^2/2}$$

using method of characteristics. I can solve it without the absolute value, but not sure how to handle them since these solutions don't seem to give a solution to this equation.

Comment: The absolute value is a norm, presumably. So you can write your quation es
$(u_t)^2  = \sum u_{x_i}^2$. Does this help?

Comment: Oh okay, so then I can factor it as $(u_t + u_x) \cdot (u_t - u_x) = 0$. So I need $u$ to at least solve one of these...

Comment: Right. And you can first solve one equation and then the other.

Comment: Okay, still little confused. If I need both to be satisfied, I get $u(t,x) = e^{-|x-t|^2/2}$  and $u(t,x) = e^{-|x+t|^2/2}$. But this can only happen if $t=0$. Neither one of these solutions solves the original equation though

Comment: Take a look at how one solves the wave equation with the D'Alambert formula.

Comment: So I get $u(t,x) = 1/2 (e^{-|x-t|^2/2} + e^{-|x+t|^2/2})$

Comment: Exactly. You could post an answer yourself, I suppose.